# Button working only on second click (any 2 clicks each)

Tags: html, angularjs, button, components, angularjs-ng-click

I have a simple, but annoying problem:

In my fragment, I have a button which should call function. 
but I have to click the button twice (any 2 clicks it works, but when i debug it any time I click the button the function is running , but only the second time I can see my output on the screen).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
           <button ng-click="$ctrl.getObject()" > GET MOVIES </button>
</div>
```

component:

```
'use strict';

const appModule = angular.module('appModule');

appModule.component('appGetData', {
    templateUrl: '/app/components/getData/getData.html',
    controller: getDataController,
    bindings:{
        movies:'='
    }
});

getDataController.$inject = [ "$http", "moviesService"];
function getDataController($http, moviesService) {
    var that = this;

    this.getObject = function(){

        moviesService.getMovies().then(function(data){
            var moviesLimit = document.getElementById("number").value;
            that.movies = data.slice(0, moviesLimit);
            console.log('DATA: ' + data);
        },function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });

    }

}
```

this component is contained in another component:

```
<app-get-data movies="$ctrl.moviesList"></app-get-data>
<app-table all-movies="$ctrl.moviesList" ></app-table>
```

Comment: Does data get logged each time? Is `getMovies()` using a third party library that is outside angular context?

Comment: this.getMovies = function(){
      return new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
      $http.get('/movies').then(
          function(data){                       // SUCCESS
            resolve(data.data);
      }, 
        function(err){
            console.log("err massage: " + err); // FAILURR
      })
    });
  }